# Shadow mapping in directx, sampler depth-texture always return 0

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx, directx-11

I am currently working on a Directx 11 shadow mapping sample.

Here are my step

- Create 2 vertex hlsl files and 2 pixel hlsl files. One is used to standar draw and the other is used to render shadow to depth-buffer.
- Create shadow-shader depthStencilView.
- Create texture and bind: D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE
- For each frame:

  - Set new render target to render shadow: **OMSetRenderTargets(0, nullptr, m_shadowDepthStencilView.Get());**
  - Clear depth-buffer: **ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView.Get(), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);**
  - Render all objects.
  - Reset render target to stander render target view: **OMSetRenderTargets(1, renderTarget.GetAddressOf(), m_standarDepthStencilView.Get());**
  - Set depth-texture (which is changed in last draw) to pixel shader resource: **PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, m_directLightShadowResourceView.GetAddressOf());**
  - Render all objects again.

Every thing seem to work except that when I get z-value in pixel shader using:

**float depthValue = depthTexture.Sample(samplerClamp, projectTexCoord).r;**

The depthValue always return 0, nomatter what.
I have check my depthTexture using visual studio graphic diagnostic and it is ok.

But When I sampler it's texture, the result is always 0.

I don't know why, I have stuck on this for a long time, so please help me.

note:

- depthTexture format: DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS
- shaderResourceView format: DXGI_FORMAT_R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS

Here are my hlsl files

**Standar vertex shader**

```js
/////////////////////
// CONSTANT BUFFER
cbuffer worldMatrixBuffer : register(b0)
{
 float4x4 worldMatrix[10];
};

cbuffer cameraBuffer : register(b1)
{
 float4x4 viewProjectionMatrix;
};

cbuffer directLightBuffer : register(b2)
{
 float4x4 directLightViewProjectionMatrix;
};


////////////////////////////
// INPUT VERTEX STRUCTURE
struct VIn
{
 float4 position : POSITION;
 float4 normal : NORMAL;
 float worldMatrixIndex : TEXCOORD0;
 float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD1;
};


//////////////////////
// OUTPUT STRUCTURE
struct VOut
{
 float3 normal : NORMAL;
 float4 position : SV_POSITION;
 float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
 float4 lightViewPosition : TEXCOORD1;
};


////////////////////////
// MAIN VERTEX SHADER
VOut main(VIn vertex)
{
 // Create output struct
 VOut output;

 // Change the position vector to be 4 units for proper matrix calculations.
 vertex.position.w = 1.0f;

 // Get world-view-projection matrix
 float4x4 currentWorldMatrix = worldMatrix[vertex.worldMatrixIndex];

 // vertex form object space to world-light-view space
 output.lightViewPosition = mul(currentWorldMatrix, vertex.position);
 output.lightViewPosition = mul(directLightViewProjectionMatrix, output.lightViewPosition);

 // vertex form object space to world-camera space;
 output.position = mul(currentWorldMatrix, vertex.position);
 output.position = mul(viewProjectionMatrix, output.position);

 // transform normal vector from object-space to world space
 output.normal = mul((float3x3)currentWorldMatrix, // convert to matrix 3x3 is important because
              // we don't want to translate normal vector
  vertex.normal);

 // we need to normalize the normal vector to preform next calculation
 output.normal = normalize(output.normal);

 // Set texture coordinate
 output.texcoord = vertex.texcoord;

 // Return output values
 return output;
}
```

**Standar pixel shader**

```js
/////////////////////
// CONSTANT BUFFER
cbuffer lightBuffer : register(b0)
{
 // Light information
 float4 lightDirection;
 float4 diffuseColor;
 float4 ambientColor;
};


//////////////////////
// INPUT STRUCTURE
struct PIn
{
 float3 normal : NORMAL;
 float4 position : SV_POSITION;
 float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
 float4 lightViewPosition : TEXCOORD1;
};


//////////////////////
// TEXTURE RESOURCE
Texture2D objectTexture : register(t0); // Register(t...) tell shader that this variable
          // retrive data from texture register 0.
Texture2D depthTexture : register(t1);


/////////////
// SAMPLER
SamplerState samplerWrap : register(s0);
SamplerState samplerClamp : register(s1);


///////////////////////
// MAIN PIXEL SHADER
float4 main(PIn pixel) : SV_TARGET
{
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // Set the bias value for fixing the floating point precision issues.
 float bias = 0.001f;

 // set minimum color to ambient color
 float4 color = ambientColor;

 // Calculate the projected texture coordinates.
 float2 projectTexCoord;
 projectTexCoord.x = pixel.lightViewPosition.x / pixel.lightViewPosition.w / 2.0f + 0.5f;
 projectTexCoord.y = -pixel.lightViewPosition.y / pixel.lightViewPosition.w / 2.0f + 0.5f;
 // By divine x and y to w we convert it lightViewPosition to uv coordinate from -1 to 1
 // convert it to 0 -> 1 coordinate simply by divine it to 2 and add 0.5

 if (saturate(projectTexCoord.x) == projectTexCoord.x
  && saturate(projectTexCoord.y) == projectTexCoord.y)
 {
  // Sample the shadow map depth value from the depth texture using the sampler at
  // the projected texture coordinate location.
  float depthValue = depthTexture.Sample(samplerClamp, projectTexCoord).r;

  // Calculate the depth of the light.
  float lightDepthValue = pixel.lightViewPosition.z / pixel.lightViewPosition.w;

  // Subtract the bias from the lightDepthValue.
  lightDepthValue = lightDepthValue - bias;

  // Compare the depth of the shadow map value and the depth of the light to determine
  // whether to shadow or to light this pixel. If the light is in front of the object
  // then light the pixel, if not then shadow this pixel since an object (occluder)
  // is casting a shadow on it.
  if (lightDepthValue > depthValue)
  {
   float4 normalLightDir = normalize(lightDirection);
    float diffuseBrigtness = saturate(   // force result to between 0 and 1
    dot(pixel.normal, normalLightDir));   // dot product of normal vector and 
   // light direction

   // add diffuse light to output color
   color += diffuseColor * diffuseBrigtness;
  }
 }

 // Multiply final color with it's texture color
 if (pixel.texcoord.x > 1)
 {
  return color * (1, 1, 1, 1);
 }
 else
 {
  return color * objectTexture.Sample(samplerWrap, pixel.texcoord);
 }
}
```

**Shadow vertex shader**

```js
/////////////////////
// CONSTANT BUFFER
cbuffer worldMatrixBuffer : register(b0)
{
 float4x4 worldMatrix[10];
};

cbuffer directLightBuffer : register(b2)
{
 float4x4 directLightViewProjectionMatrix;
};


////////////////////////////
// INPUT VERTEX STRUCTURE
struct VIn
{
 float4 position : POSITION;
 float4 normal : NORMAL;
 float worldMatrixIndex : TEXCOORD0;
 float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD1;
};


//////////////////////
// OUTPUT STRUCTURE
struct VOut
{
 float4 position : SV_POSITION;
};


////////////////////////
// MAIN VERTEX SHADER
VOut main(VIn vertex)
{
 // Create output struct
 VOut output;

 // Get world-view-projection matrix
 float4x4 currentWorldMatrix = worldMatrix[vertex.worldMatrixIndex];

 // vertex form object space to world-camera space
 output.position = mul(currentWorldMatrix, vertex.position);
 output.position = mul(directLightViewProjectionMatrix, output.position);

 return output;
}
```

**And it's pixel shader, which do nothing**

```js
////////////////////////
// PIXEL INPUT STRUCT
struct PIn
{
 float4 position : SV_POSITION;
};

float4 main(PIn pixel) : SV_TARGET
{
 return float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: What hardware feature level/shader profiles are you using?

Comment: I'm using D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0.

Comment: I have try a snippet: float4 main(PIn pixel) : SV_TARGET
{ return depthTexture.Sample(samplerWrap, pixel.texcoord); } and the result is pure black. There must be something wrong with my texture but I can't figure out why.

Comment: I have figure it out. I feel so stupid now. - The reason why I can not depth-buffer is because I set shader resource using PSSetShaderResource befor I release it's depth buffer (which was bind in OSState). - The only thing I need to do is move the code PSSetShaderResource to after the code OSSetRenderTarget and suddenly it's work.

Comment: Sorry every one to waste your time on this.

Comment: Make sure you try the ``D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG`` switch and check for ERRORS or WARNINGS. The debug layer would have mentioned the pipeline hazard.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry every one, I have figured it out. I feel really stupid.

- The reason I cannot read my depth buffer is because I use PSSetShaderResource before OMSetRenderTarget. What this mean is that my depth buffer is still bind to OM state and so it cannot be binded to PS state.
- I only need to move the code a few line down and every thing just work

I am really sorry every one who has wasted there time on my question.